# Problems with formatting dates in java

Tags: java, date, format

I'm the doing the following

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

The output is weird date patterns such as

2013-10-28 04:10:43.000000222 (its June, not October)

While the time, year and day seems to be fine, the month is playing games. Everytime I run the code, its coming out to be a different month, sometimes even going out of range, like

2013-58-28 04:15:43.000000654

Also, if I'm printing the date without formatting it, it seems to be fine, concluding (I think so) that my system date is fine.

Any idea what's the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use (capital) `MM` to indicate month; `mm` is for minutes only.  The [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) has all the date format symbols.

Comment: Ah, beaten by 16 seconds... :P

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2013-10-28 04:10:43.000000222".replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
```

## Using java.time

The [Answer by rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17354535/642706) is correct. But now both the Question and that Answer are outdated.

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Also, your input string has nanoseconds but those old classes are limited to milliseconds. Fortunately the java.time classes handle nanoseconds.

### ISO 8601

Your input string nearly complies with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. To comply fully, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2013-10-28 04:10:43.000000222".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

The java.time classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### `LocalDateTime`

Your input string lacks any indication of an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or a time zone. So we parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2013-10-28T04:10:43.000000222

As a `LocalDateTime`, this does *not* represent a moment on the timeline. Is that 4 AM in India, 4 AM in France, or 4 AM in Québec? Those would all be different points on the timeline with the 4 AM in India happening several hours earlier in history than the 4 AM times in France or Québec.

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you know for certain the intended time zone, apply it.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2013-10-28T04:10:43.000000222-04:00[America/Montreal]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).